# Visual C# и Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Привет всем, скажите в чём смысл скачивать/покупать студию если можно скачать лицензию с офф.сайта отдельно C#? Я установил и студию и C# написал одно и тоже и там и там, всё работает так же, так скажите зачем студия если ты программируешь только на одном языке?

Comment: Как это вы скачали C#? Это язык программирования, а не программное обеспечение. (ПО)

Answer (score 2):

Ну как я понимаю, если ставишь C# (не знал что такое вообще возможно)то ты пишешь только под консоль. 
А Студия VS представляет богатый выбор для создания приложений как и консольных, так и графических(всем привычные 'окна') и да как сказали облегчающего много + Visual Assist X тоже стоит внимания облегчает, а как скачать VS и Visual Assist X думаю вы найдете сами.
Да при установке VS можно выбрать какие пакеты ставить, не нужно отключить и всё.

Мой выбор всегда был VS, всё и в одном месте.

Comment: Под словом C# я подразумевал Visual C#, а по поводу студии... я как дурак пол года на VC# :( Обидно((

Comment: Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать ``Visual Assist X``, он затачивался под C++, лучше взглянуть в сторону великолепного ``Resharper``

Comment: Спасибо за информацию об Resharper, не знал о нем надо будет попробовать.

Answer (score 1):

В студии есть огромное множество всяких облегчающих жизнь фишек, которых нет в Visual C# Express. В таблице сравнения они должны быть перечислены.